# Mocking the IQueryable content in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, nunit, iqueryable

I have a method which uses IQueryable to get the value from another class, when I try to mock it normally and my expected result is always "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Nop.Core.Domain.OnTrack.Road]" in Nunit. Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

Implementation Class:

```
public async Task<Track> OnTrack(int warId, int cardno, string trackName)
{
    trackName = GetAssignedtrackName(trackName, cardno);
    Track track;

    using (var scope = TransactionScopeExtensions.AsyncScope())
    {
        track = await (from s in _trackRepository.Table
            where s.Name == trackName && s.warId == warId
            select s).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (track != null && track.CarVariantId.HasValue)
        {
            throw new ErrorCodeException(trackAssignmentErrorCode.AlreadyAssigned);
        }

        // Get car variant ID
        var carVariantId =
            (from cv in _carVariantRepository.Table
             join c in _carRepository.Table on cv.CarId equals c.Id
             where !c.Deleted && !cv.Deleted && c.Id == cardno
             orderby cv.Published descending
             select cv.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (carVariantId == 0)
        {
            throw new ErrorCodeException(CatalogErrorCode.CarVariantNotFound);
        }

        if (track != null)
        {
            track.CarVariantId = carVariantId;
            await _trackRepository.UpdateAsync(track);
        }
        else
        {
            track = new track
            {
                Name = trackName,
                CarVariantId = carVariantId,
                Quantity = 0,
                warId = warId
            };
            await _trackRepository.InsertAsync(track);
        }

        scope.Complete();
    }

    return track;
}
```

Repository Code:

```
public partial interface IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    T GetById(object id);
    Task<T> GetByIdAsync(object id);
    void Insert(T entity, bool saveChanges = true);
    Task InsertAsync(T entity, bool saveChanges = true);
    void InsertRange(IEnumerable<T> entity, bool saveChanges = true);
    Task InsertRangeAsync(IEnumerable<T> entity, bool saveChanges = true);
    void Update(T entity, bool saveChanges = true);
    Task UpdateAsync(T entity, bool saveChanges = true);
    void Delete(T entity, bool saveChanges = true);
    Task DeleteAsync(T entity, bool saveChanges = true);
    int SaveChanges();
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
    IQueryable<T> Table { get; }
    void AttachAndUpdateProperty<TProperty>(T entity, params Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>[] modifiedProperties);
}
```

And my test Code looks like this:

```
    IRepository<Track> _itrackRepository;
    IRepository<Car> _icarRepository;
    IRepository<CarVariant> _icarvariantRepository;
    ITrackService _trackService;
    Car _car1, _car2;
    CarVariant _carvar1, _carvar2;
    Track _track1, _track2;

    [SetUp] // has all the mockup data
    public void setup()
    {
        _track1 = new Track()
        {
            Id = 123,
            Name = "PER123",
            Quantity = 1,
            CarVariantId = 123,
            QuantityOnHold = 1,
            WarId = 123,

        };
        _track2 = new Track()
        {
            Id = 11,
            Name = "PER11",
            Quantity = 1,
            CarVariantId = 11,

        };
        _car1 = new Car()
        { Id = 123, Deleted = false, Name = "PER" };
        _car2 = new Car()
        { Id = 11, Deleted = false, Name = "PER" };
        _carvar1 = new CarVariant()
        {
            Name = "PER123",
            Id = 123,
            Deleted = false,

        };
        _carvar2 = new CarVariant()
        {
            Name = "PER11",
            Id = 11,
            Deleted = false
        };




        _itrackRepository=MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepository<Track>>();
        _itrackRepository.Expect(x => x.Table).Return(new List<Track>() { _track1, _track2 }.AsQueryable());
        _icarRepository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepository<Car>>();
        _icarRepository.Expect(x => x.Table).Return(new List<Car>() { _car1, _car2 }.AsQueryable());
        _icarvariantRepository = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IRepository<CarVariant>>();
        _icarvariantRepository.Expect(x => x.Table).Return(new List<CarVariant>() { _carvar1, _carvar2 }.AsQueryable());
        _trackService = new TrackService(_itrackRepository, _icarvariantRepository, _icarRepository);
    }

[Test]
public async Task AssignTrack_test0001()
{
    var temp = await (_trackService.OnTrack(321, 321, "fre"));

    AreEqual("PER123", temp);
}
```

Comment: You code is too long. Is all of this code necessary to generate your problem? Can you provide a shorter piece of code that can also demonstrate the issue you are facing?

Comment: Hi Yacoub, I am trying to mockup an IQueryable content and am not able to, it will be helpful if you can point me to some snippet, I tried to implement by using the below format

        var temp = await (_trackService.OnTrack(321, 321, "fre"));
        AreEqual("PER123", temp);

Here .OnTrack() has a link to the repository which constructs the IQueryable content and push the result to the method and trying to valuate the result on my Nunit

Comment: I really cannot understand. When you say mockup, do you mean creating a fake implementation of some dependency for unit testing? How does `OnTrack` method create a mockup? Your question is really not easily understandable. I suggest that you work on the question. For example, delete unnecessary code. Does every line in the code your provide necessary to make us understand your problem? I am guessing you only need a few lines of code to demonstrate your problem.